# Can you correct any errors I made in this code?

Tags: java

Make the Pixel gotten using getPixel( 2, 3 )
be made black with setColor(java.awt.Color.Black) and then the Picture
be shown with show( ) Hint: You MUST declare and use a Picture reference
variable, with code like Picture p.

```
public static void main(String[] a)
{
    new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile( );
}
```

Here's my answer, can anyone please tell me if this is correct and if i need to make any changes? any help would be appreciated. Also, this isn't a hw question, im reviewing for an exam. So if you're going to tell me to go do my own hw, don't bother answering. :)

```
public static void main(String[] a)
{
    Picture p = new Picture;
    new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile( );
    Pixel pixRef;
    pixRef.getPixel(2,3);
    pixRef.setColor(java.awt.Color.Black);
    p.show();
}
```

Comment: first code .. add ")"

Comment: are you using an editor? If not, you should consider using one. You are missing `)` at the end of `new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile( )`

Comment: What are the Picture and Pixel classes?

Comment: i am actually not given the picture and Pixel classes. All I have to do is write a few lines of code in the main method to color the pixels at that specific coordinate

Comment: Your `new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile());` does not seems to be assigned to a variable. Also The instance pixRef of type Pixel does not have a reference to the Picture p so the use of pixRef can't affect the Picture p.

Comment: You are really expected to be able to sort out basic syntax errors by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will fail your exam like this.

```
public static void main(String[] a)
{
  Picture p; // constructor is a method - but seems you instantiate it in next line
  p =new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile( )); // assign it to p
  Pixel pixRef = new Pixel(); //avoid nullpointerexception! but logically you should get the pixel from the picture, which displayed in next line, can remove the "new Pixel()";
  pixRef = p.getPixel(2,3); // Shouldn't you get pixelref from picture?
  pixRef.setColor(java.awt.Color.Black);
  p.show(); // I don't understand this. Where do you show this? shouldn't you put it inside a Frame or something?
}
```

Comment: No need to create a new Pixel if you are referencing it to p.getPixel the line after.

Comment: you are correct @Lynch, but I also want to show the mistake in the original code.

Comment: Yes I understand. keep it this way then.

Comment: +1 Really good response, teach rather then tell

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] a)
{

Picture p = new Picture;  //what are you trying to call here?  you must try checking out how to create an object  it must be "Picture p = new Picture();" , and if you have just defined a parameterised constructor in Picture class and need an object of that directly do it this was
"Picture p = new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile( ));

new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile( )); // must be enclosed properly
Pixel pixRef;
pixRef.getPixel(2,3);  // must be initialized before using the instance methods "Pixel pixRef = new Pixel();"
pixRef.setColor(java.awt.Color.Black);
p.show();
}
```